# How to deploy a DLL that is constantly changing?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, deployment, dll

I have created several small applications that use my own DLL. The problem is, this DLL is constantly changing. My current solution to this problem is that I have a Setup project in the class library solution that creates and registers the DLL. In all my applications I then have to open the solution and re-reference the newly created/registered DLL. **Then** I have to re-compile their setup projects, uninstall the old applications, and then re-install the new application.

There has to be a better way and I'm just not sure because I'm fairly new to all this. I have looked into ClickOnce but I don't think that will solve my issue as I cannot publish a class library. I have looked into checking version numbers but I must be doing something wrong because it doesn't work either.

*I understand that once a DLL is created and being used in an application it should essentially not be touched. I do not have that option in this situation. It is constantly updated. Done.*

So, is there a better way? A point in the direction of a guide or related question/answer/forum would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**: The DLL is not constantly changing during runtime but it is constantly evolving to allow more functionality and detail within the other applications. Also, one big thing I guess I should have mentioned is the Public interface is constantly chaning - usually adding new methods.

Comment: You have a dll that is constantly changing during runtime?

Comment: What changes in the DLL? If it's only the internal implementation (no changes to the public interface), you can just replace the DLL without recompiling everything

Comment: Is your dll signed, and if so are you changing its version number constantly too? If so, just leave the version number. All of the above steps can be done from a cmd script, so maybe just automate your current process.

Comment: What is a DLL??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure the references to your DLL specify SpecificVersion=false. Then just deploy each new version into the GAC and that should do the trick.
Eventually, you can also manually force versions using [Binding Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: This is a great solution. Exactly what the OP wanted. Other solutions such as NuGet require recompilation and redeployment of the other projects.

Answer (score 1):

A solution you can try is to use a single solution for your project and reference the project wherever it needs to go.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started)

You could set up an internal Nuget repository (really just a folder that stores nupkg files.)  Then when you build a new DLL, you can update the apps as needed in studio.  This would ensure it had the latest version.  They shouldn't need a redployment unless there are bugs in the DLL that you're fixing.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is as follows:

- Physically separate the interface from the implementation.  e.g. AssemblyA is the interface, the application (AssemblyB say) knows only the interface at compile time.  The implementation (AssemblyC) also knows/references AssemblyA of course.  The point being that AssemblyB does not reference AssemblyC.  This will require you to use an IoC container (like MS Unity 2.0 but there are many others) in order to resolve and instantiate your concretes at runtime.
- Write an update process that finds the new AssemblyC.dll, replaces the local copy and uses reflection along with the IoCContainer to 'load' the new implementation at what ever interval you require, typically app start up.

The above relies on your interface being stable.  If it isn't, you may be able to write a (more) stable [Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).